# Julia - Mutable struct with Attribute which is a Function and @code_warntype

Tags: performance, struct, julia

In Julia, I want to have a mutable struct with an attribute which type is a Function, this function will have arguments:

```
mutable struct Class_example
    function_with_arguments::Function
    some_attribute::Int
    function Class_example() new() end
    function Class_example(function_wa::Function, some_a::Int)
        this = new()
        this.function_with_arguments = function_wa
        this.some_attribute = some_a
        this
    end
end
```

I also want to do an action on this mutable struct :

```
function do_action_on_class(Class::Class_example)
    return Class.function_with_arguments(Class.some_attribute ,2.0, true)
end
```

Then I define a function that aims to be my class attribute :

```
function do_something_function(arg1::Int, arg2::Float64, arg3::Bool)
    if arg2 < 5.0
        for i in 1:arg1
            # Do Something Interesting
            @show arg3
        end
    end
    return 1
end
```

Finally, `function_whith_arguments` will be launch a huge number of time in my whole project, this is only a minimal example, so I want all this code to be very quick. That's why I use @code_warntype according to Julia's documentation [Performance Tips](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/index.html#man-code-warntype-1)

However, @code_warntype tells me this

```
body::Any
15 1 ─ %1 = (Base.getfield)(Class, :function_with_arguments)::Function
getproperty
%2 = (Base.getfield)(Class, :some_attribute)::Int64
%3 = (%1)(%2, 2.0, true)::Any                                     │ 
return %3
```

Here, `::Function` and the two `::Any` are in red, indicating Julia can improve the performance of the code with a better implementation. So what's this correct implementation ? How should I declare my attribute function_whith_arguments as a Function type in my mutable struct ?

Whole code compilable :

```
mutable struct Class_example
    function_with_arguments::Function
    some_attribute::Int
    function Class_example() new() end
    function Class_example(function_wa::Function, some_a::Int)
        this = new()
        this.function_with_arguments = function_wa
        this.some_attribute = some_a
        this
    end
end


function do_action_on_class(Class::Class_example)
    return Class.function_with_arguments(Class.some_attribute ,2.0, true)
end

function do_something_function(arg1::Int, arg2::Float64, arg3::Bool)
    if arg2 < 5.0
        for i in 1:arg1
            # Do Something Interesting
            @show arg3
        end
    end
    return 1
end

function main()
    class::Class_example = Class_example(do_something_function, 4)
    @code_warntype do_action_on_class(class)
end

main()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will be efficient (well inferred). Note that I only modified (and renamed) the type.

```
mutable struct MyClass{F<:Function}
    function_with_arguments::F
    some_attribute::Int
end


function do_action_on_class(Class::MyClass)
    return Class.function_with_arguments(Class.some_attribute ,2.0, true)
end

function do_something_function(arg1::Int, arg2::Float64, arg3::Bool)
    if arg2 < 5.0
        for i in 1:arg1
            # Do Something Interesting
            @show arg3
        end
    end
    return 1
end

function main()
    class::MyClass = MyClass(do_something_function, 4)
    @code_warntype do_action_on_class(class)
end

main()
```

**What did I do?**

- If you care about performance, you should [never have fields of an abstract type](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/index.html#Avoid-fields-with-abstract-type-1), and `isabstracttype(Function) == true`. What you should do instead is parameterize on that fields type (`F` above, which can be any function. Note that `isconcretetype(typeof(sin)) == true`). This way, for any particular instance of `MyCall` the precise concrete type of every field is known at compile time.
- Irrelevant for performance but: There is no need for a constructor that simply assigns all the arguments to all the fields. Such a [constructor](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/constructors/) is defined by default implicitly.

You can read more about parametric types [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/#Parametric-Types-1).

On a side note, what you are doing looks a lot like trying to write OO-style in Julia. I'd recommend to not do this but instead use Julia the Julia way using multiple dispatch.